# Why are my 2D world click-positions offset after camera movement?

Tags: xna, c#, camera, coordinates

I'm writing a 2D game engine. I need to add a camera to my world that can zoom in and out as well as move away from its initial position at `(0,0)` at the center of the world.

The main issue can be seen in [this video](http://youtu.be/ow1jCSUpwPg). When the camera hasn't yet moved (still at `0,0`), I can click anywhere in the visible world and the click is mapped to the correct world position. I can even zoom and everything including the mouse position is scaled correctly. However, the moment I move the camera, the position becomes offset by a percentage of the camera movement. (This is clearer in the video.)

I have tried calculating the draw position and world mouse position in many different ways, but I always get the same issue.

What might be wrong?

Here's the code for both *object position to screen position* and *mouse position to world position conversion*:

```
public Vector2 GetDrawCoord(Vector2 position)
{
    return new Vector2(((position.X - cameraCenter.X)) * zoom + graphics.Viewport.Width / 2, 
        graphics.Viewport.Height - ((position.Y - cameraCenter.Y) * zoom + graphics.Viewport.Height / 2));
}

public Vector2 GetClickCoord(Vector2 position)
{
    return new Vector2((position.X - graphics.Viewport.Width / 2 + cameraCenter.X) / zoom, 
        (graphics.Viewport.Height / 2 - position.Y + cameraCenter.Y) / zoom);
}
```

Update:

New code:

```
Vector3 vec = graphics.Viewport.Unproject(new Vector3(position.X, position.Y, 0f), 
            Matrix.CreateOrthographic((float)graphics.Viewport.Width, (float)graphics.Viewport.Height, 0f, 0f), 
            cameraMatrix, 
            Matrix.Identity);
```

Comment: This seems to be the same question as [Why are my 2D positions "off" after adding a camera transformation in XNA?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11122/why-are-my-2d-positions-off-after-adding-a-camera-transformation-in-xna) though it seems the actual issue there was different...

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't (incorrectly) using matrices, but i am now. Just trying to figure all the matrices stuff out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Viewport.Unproject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.viewport.unproject.aspx) method exactly for this.

- For the **source** which is a vector3 you should specify your
  screenspace position into the xy members. The z member of the vector
  corresponds to the view frustum near and far planes. 0 means you are
  on the near plane, 1 means that you are on the far plane and in
  between means you are between by that value.
- The **projection** matrix should be an orthographics matrix if you
  are doing a 2D game. You can create an ortho projection by calling
  [Matrix.CreateOrthographic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195662.aspx) and specifying your screen dimensions
  and some near-far frustum values which could be irrelevant in a 2D
  game.
- The **view** matrix is your camera transformation matrix.
- The **world** matrix is a world transform matrix. It should be
  Matrix.Identity if you are not transforming you world.

Comment: Thanks, i had a look into this, but the vector3 coming out of `CreateOrthographic` is coming out NaN,NaN,NaN. I've added my code to my question.

Comment: So, ive fixed it now. but when my mouse pointer is positioned at the center of the screen. I'm getting a vector the equals the center of the screen but negative(-400, -240), that cant be right can it?

Comment: I can't say why are you getting those values without seeing your position and matrix values. Also try to create ortho matrix with 0 for nearplane and 1 for farplane values if you are having problems.